# SQL Selecting from 3 tables returns syntax error

Tags: sql, linq, ms-access, select, join

I have 3 tables on which i need to select data from using ms-access DB

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.columnID, b.column1
From TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
   ON a.columnID = b.columnID INNER JOIN TableC c
   ON c.columnID = a.columnRelativeID
WHERE a.columnID=16
```

Although when I try to execute the query I receive Syntax error.

In addition, when i remove the second join, with the third table, the query works fine so this is the place where the error stays.

This [example of joining 3 tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213227%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) didn't help me understand where my problem is.

Is it OK if I just select from two tables and complete the third-table data from a LINQ in C#? I have the Third-table data in a data source in my code

Thanks in advance,

Oz.

Comment: For this particular example you don't actually need to join onto TableC

Comment: Can you give us the **complete, exact** error you're getting?? The SQL seems fine - there must be some hint in the error as to what's wrong...

Comment: It would also have been useful to know what database server you are using.  As Shakti noted below in his answer, it might be a case sensitivity issue.  But that depends on the DB.

Comment: <Message> in query expression <expression>. (Error 3075)
The expression you typed is not valid for the reason indicated in the message. Make sure you have typed field names and punctuation correctly, and then try the operation again.

Comment: Post the error message as you received

Comment: Already posted 1 comment before of you

Comment: Unless this is a copy and paste error `ON c.columnID = a.columnRelativeID` seems wrong to me. Is the column really named **columnRelativeID**?

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that is an *ms-access* error code?

Comment: yes it is.. Why can't I select from 3 tables in Access?

Comment: Yes this is the real name of the column

Comment: @oz radiano: it might **help** to actually **tell** everyone that you're using Access (and use an appropriate tag for it, too!)

Comment: OK.. I'll let know next time + edit this specific question and tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely select from three (or more) tables in MS Access. However, you have to use Access' craptastic parenthesis system which pairs tables together in the From clause.

```
Select A.Column1, A.Column2, A.Column3, A.ColumnID, B.Column1
From (Table1 AS A 
    Inner Join Table2 AS B 
        On A.ColumnID = B.ColumnId) 
    Inner Join Table3 AS C 
        ON A.ColumnRelativeId = C.ColumnId
Where A.ColumnId = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.columnID, b.column1 
From TableA a , TableB b, TableC
WHERE a.columnID = b.columnID 
AND c.columnID = a.columnRelativeID 
AND a.columnID=16
```

Comment: Why would you suggest an implicit JOIN? Jet/ACE optimizes implicit JOINs identically to the equivalent explicit JOIN, so there's no penalty in doing so in simple cases like this, but it really only works with INNER JOINs.

Comment: suggested because it is equivalent to whatthe OP wishes, and this syntax is much cleaner than wierd perenthesis matching.